# Rabbitmq message expiration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Messages are not getting dropped after the expiration time.
Using spring-rabbit java client I am sending the message with the header set with **expiration:10000**.

For reference here is the message present in Rabbitmq queue,

Properties
priority:   0

delivery_mode:  2

headers:
expiration: 10000

content_encoding:   UTF-8

content_type:   text/plain

Please help me if I need to set anything in Rabbitmq server or any extra parameter need to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expiration` is a well-known message property, not a simple `header`.

Properties are known to the broker, headers are generally arbitrary key/values used by the source and destination application, although some `x-*` headers have meaning to RabbitMQ.

This message expires just fine:

[image]

With spring-amqp, it's a property on `MessageProperties`.

Comment: Thank you Gary Russell,
I was setting in header, due to that it was not working ,
Now I set it in properties and its working.
Thanks Once again.